# Firebase Firestore authenticated user write data freely after tampering client side code

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firebase Firestore authenticated user write data freely after tampering code, is it possible?

For example, after setting firebase security rule to only allow user write document created by themselves, can hacker tampering the client side code and upVote their own post voteCount from 1 to 1000?

I understand we can set security rule to only allow increment of 1 vote per one write of document. I want to focusing on knowing whether hacker can modified client side code and use the app again as usual. A high confident answer is greatly appreciated. Thank you. I am a happy firebase user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security purposes, you should assume that the client code has been compromised.  After all, it's running on a machine or device that you don't have control over.  It's actually pretty easy for someone to change the way JavaScript works in a browser environment.

Comment: Hey Doug, good to see u. Let’s say the hacker understand how Firestore work very well. Any code after docRef.updateData/setData can be tampering on client side to allow them modify the doc as they wish if security rules allowed? And to prevent this one of the solution is I must use cloud function to update voteCount, set security rules to prevent user directly update voteCount from client code, because hacker can change the client code. Is this the right way to think for security purpose? Agian, I am big fan of Firebase, happy Firebase  developer

Comment: No, security rules are evaluated on the server and can't be tampered with.  That's why it's so important for you to use them, since the client can't be trusted.

Comment: I knew security rules can’t be tampered with and evaluated on server. I wish to confirm some security structure, on my security rules I should set all user can’t update all post’s voteCount value to prevent hacker update voteCount value from client side, is this right ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Your security rules will prevent whatever actions they do not specifically allow.  If you don't want something to happen, make sure that logic is reflected in your rules.

Comment: alright, security rules is the best gatekeeper. Bear me for asking again, so hacker can tampering the iOS and android code, after that still can login to the apps by using their original email and password?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has many security and data validation features in its rules system. All security and data verification needs to be done or verified within firebase rules. You can never trust that a client app/web-interface is behaving.

Perhaps votes are stored as a set of user-id: vote, and a user is only allowed to create a slot with their own id, and vote can be 1,-1 for example.

Comment: I thought about this, then the hacker can modify the code on client to keep creating bunch of random fake words as uid and keep upVote. Does this means my security rule should only allow user write certain field value in document created by themselves

Comment: The hacker can try whatever random values they like, including other users ids (if they manage to guess them). No matter, on firebase you have a rule that says you are only allowed to add a vote entry that matches your own id.

Comment: Good thinking. But the limitation is doc max size is 1mb, which the doc would not contain more than  300k unique uid, so the max voteCount is limited, user also need download the whole 500kb or 800kb or 1mb file as vote count increased, which will add burden to app performance and more data to download on slow internet. Thank for telling me hacker can tampering the client code as they wish and it is dangerous, so I can set better security structure